# Translate this JavaScript Gibberish please?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to modify and update an old Greasemonkey script with the goal of automatically adding an affiliate ID to all Amazon links.  I'm a novice when it comes to JavaScript, but I'm usually pretty good about modifying existing scripts in any language.  There's just one line here that I can't wrap my head around.

The script I started with is outdated, so I don't know if there is a problem with the syntax or if the link format has changed.  Can somebody please help me understand what this line is doing so I can make changes to it?

```
const affiliateLink = /(obidos.(ASIN.{12}([^\/]*(=|%3D)[^\/]*\/)*|redirect[^\/]*.(tag=)?))[^\/&]+/i;
```

Comment: It's not gibberish, it's just a plain regular expression. It doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, you asked for it :)

Start the regular expression:

> /

Start a group operation:

> (

Search for the text "obidos" followed by any single character

> obidos.

Open another group operator:

> (

Search for the text "ASIN" followed by any 12 characters

> ASIN.{12}

Another group operation:

> (

Followed by 0 or more characters that are not slashes:

> [^\/]*

Group operation searching for an '=' character or a url encoded '=' (%3D):

> (=|%3D)

Followed by 0 or more characters that are not slashes:

> [^\/]*

Followed by slash (and closes the current group), which can be repeated 0 or more times:

> \/)*

Allows the pattern to match if the previous group was found OR everything to the right of the bar is matched:

> |

Matches the text "redirect" followed by 0 or more chatacters that are not a slash:

> redirect[^\/]*

Matches any single character, followed optionally by the text "tag=":

> .(tag=)?

Closes the two group operations we're currently still inside of:

> ))

Followed by one or more characters that are not a slash or &:

> [^\/&]+

Closes the regular expression:

> /

Comment: Had to +1 just for the effort

Comment: Heh, thanks. That was kind of ridiculous, but I felt motivated for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Download a copy of expresso, its a great utility for this and comes in handy for all this stuff. then just place the regex into that (everything between the starting slashes and ending slash).

I would describe what string it matches e.c.t. but its fairly complex as theres lots of components to it. Its easier for you to look at it yourself. expresso provides a more english explanation of each pattern